# Pandas throwing error on compressed file (xz)

Tags: pandas, lzma

```
import pandas as pd
import lzma

df = pd.read_csv('final.csv', headers = None)

with open('/xzfolder/final.xz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(lzma.compress(df.to_records(index=False), format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ))    

df = pd.read_csv('/xzfolder/final.xz', headers = None)
```

Above is my code. I am compressing my csv using lzma...but when I read compressed file I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 8: invalid continuation byte

Comment: pandas.read_csv accepts only text files. It cannot read your compressed binary file. You will have to uncompress it first and then use pandas.read_csv

Comment: I have not tried with a `xz` compressed file but with a `gzip` compressed file, I can read it directly with the `read_csv` option if I pass the compression  - `pd.read_csv("filename.gz", headers=None, compression="gzip")` works

Comment: @Mortz Ok. But question is not talking about gzip.

Comment: What I meant to say was that you can try to pass the compression parameter directly - which you don't seem to have tried - i.e. `df = pd.read_csv('file.xz', compression='...')`

Comment: @Mortz it still give the error. I have tried. you can try as well just to confirm.

Comment: Yup - same error

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and faced the same error. I also tried to "unxz" the created file using a command line utility (xz on linux) but even that seemed to be giving out garbage - indicating that there is something wrong with the file creation.

I changed the code to use `.to_string().encode()` - thereby forcing a bytes object and it works

```
import lzma
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.txt', header=None)
with open('somez.xz', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(lzma.compress(df.to_string().encode()
           , format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ))

df_re = pd.read_csv('somez.xz')
```